# Split a redshift column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a my table in redshift that contains some aggregation of data

```
Product_id , options_id
1,           tag1:value1&tag2:value2
```

I want instead to have a view that displays them as follows:

```
 Product_id , tag1 , tag2
 1 ,           value1 , value 2
```

Is there a way to do this?

I can only find people online that split it into multiple rows instead, like here:

https://www.holistics.io/blog/splitting-array-string-into-rows-in-amazon-redshift-or-mysql/

but that does not serve my purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [split_part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html)

```
select product_id, 
       split_part(split_part('tag1:value1&tag2:value2', '&', 1), ':', 1) as tag1, 
       split_part(split_part('tag1:value1&tag2:value2', '&', 2), ':', 1) as tag2
from the_table
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the columns name be generic? as in not hardcode tag1, but be the actual value that was in the column

Comment: @ArekKrawczyk: no that's not possible in SQL